# HierarchyTasksList with a custom schema and extra view gives error list not found

Tags: 2013, list-view, task-list, schema, custom-schema

I am creating a HierarchyTasksList with a custom schema.
When I add an extra view with a BaseViewId="10" or any other not used number I get an error.
However when I change the BaseViewId to "1". Everything works fine. Why is this happening?

I am using SP2013.

My List instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="Tasks"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="171"
                FeatureId="f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0"
                Url="Lists/Taken"
                CustomSchema="LITaken\Schema.xml">
  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

My Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Hierarchy tasks" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" Url="Lists/Taken" BaseType="0">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0108">
        <Folder TargetName="Task" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="LinkTitle" ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Task_Name;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle" />
      <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Task_Name;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
      <Field Name="Title" ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Task_Name;" Sealed="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" />
      <Field ID="{c3a92d97-2b77-4a25-9698-3ab54874bc6f}" Name="Predecessors" Type="LookupMulti" Mult="TRUE" Required="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Tasks_Predecessors;" StaticName="Predecessors" List="Self" ShowField="Title" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{a8eb573e-9e11-481a-a8c9-1104a54b2fbd}" Type="Choice" Name="Priority" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Priority;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Priority">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Priority_High;</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Priority_Normal;</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Priority_Low;</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
        <MAPPINGS>
          <MAPPING Value="1">$Resources:core,Priority_High;</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="2">$Resources:core,Priority_Normal;</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="3">$Resources:core,Priority_Low;</MAPPING>
        </MAPPINGS>
        <Default>$Resources:core,Priority_Normal;</Default>
      </Field>
      <Field Type="Choice" ID="{c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76}" Name="Status" DisplayName="$Resources:core,TaskStatus;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Status">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Tasks_NotStarted;</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Tasks_InProgress</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Tasks_Completed</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Tasks_Deferred</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>$Resources:core,Tasks_Waiting</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
        <MAPPINGS>
          <MAPPING Value="1">$Resources:core,Tasks_NotStarted;</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="2">$Resources:core,Tasks_InProgress</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="3">$Resources:core,Tasks_Completed</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="4">$Resources:core,Tasks_Deferred</MAPPING>
          <MAPPING Value="5">$Resources:core,Tasks_Waiting</MAPPING>
        </MAPPINGS>
        <Default>$Resources:core,Tasks_NotStarted;</Default>
      </Field>
      <Field Type="Number" Name="PercentComplete" ID="{d2311440-1ed6-46ea-b46d-daa643dc3886}" Percentage="TRUE" Min="0" Max="1" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Percent_Complete;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="PercentComplete">
        <Default>0</Default>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{53101f38-dd2e-458c-b245-0c236cc13d1a}" Type="UserMulti" List="UserInfo" Name="AssignedTo" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" ShowField="ImnName" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Assigned_To;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="AssignedTo">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{7662cd2c-f069-4dba-9e35-082cf976e170}" Type="Note" RichText="TRUE" RestrictedMode="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" Name="Body" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Description;" Sortable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Body">
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007}" Type="DateTime" Name="StartDate" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Start_Date;" Format="DateOnly" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Relative" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="StartDate">
      </Field>
      <Field Type="DateTime" ID="{cd21b4c2-6841-4f9e-a23a-738a65f99889}" Name="DueDate" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Due_Date;" Format="DateOnly" FriendlyDisplayFormat="Relative" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="DueDate">
      </Field>
      <Field Type="Lookup" Indexed="TRUE" Name="ParentID" ID="{fd447db5-3908-4b47-8f8c-a5895ed0aa6a}" Hidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" List="Self" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="Cascade" ShowField="ID" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Parent_ID;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ParentID">
      </Field>
      <Field Type="Calculated" Name="Checkmark" ID="{ebf1c037-47eb-4355-998d-47ce9f2cc047}" Required="FALSE" ResultType="Boolean" ReadOnly="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Check_Mark_Field;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Checkmark">
        <Formula>=PercentComplete&gt;=1</Formula>
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field>
      <Field Type="RelatedItems" Name="RelatedItems" ID="{d2a04afc-9a05-48c8-a7fa-fa98f9496141}" ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="FALSE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Related_Links_Field;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="RelatedItems">
      </Field>
      <Field Type="UserMulti" List="UserInfo" ID="{1982e408-0f94-4149-8349-16f301d89134}" Name="PreviouslyAssignedTo" Mult="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Previously_Assigned_To_Field;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="PreviouslyAssignedTo">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="GANTT">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <Toolbar Position="After" Type="Freeform">
          <IfHasRights>
            <RightsChoices>
              <RightsGroup PermAddListItems="required" />
            </RightsChoices>
            <Then>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<div class="tb"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/caladd.gif?rev=23" alt="" />&#160;<a class="ms-addnew" id="idAddNewTask" href="]]></HTML>
              <URL Cmd="New" />
              <HTML><![CDATA[" onclick="javascript:NewItem(']]></HTML>
              <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
                <URL Cmd="New" />
              </ScriptQuote>
              <HTML><![CDATA[', true);javascript:return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
              <HTML>$Resources:core,addnewitem;</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[</a></div>]]></HTML>
            </Then>
          </IfHasRights>
        </Toolbar>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Predecessors">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="GUID">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="GanttTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate" Type="GanttStartDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="GanttEndDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="GanttPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Predecessors" Type="GanttPredecessors">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ParentID" Type="HierarchyParentID">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,All_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="True" Url="AllItems.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" DefaultView="TRUE" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query />
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Late_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" Url="late.aspx" ReqAuth="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <And>
              <Or>
                <IsNull>
                  <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" />
                </IsNull>
                <Neq>
                  <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete">
                  </FieldRef>
                  <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
                </Neq>
              </Or>
              <Lt>
                <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
                </FieldRef>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                  <Today>
                  </Today>
                </Value>
              </Lt>
            </And>
          </Where>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
            </FieldRef>
            <FieldRef Name="Priority">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="3" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Incomplete_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" Url="Upcoming.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <And>
              <Or>
                <IsNull>
                  <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" />
                </IsNull>
                <Neq>
                  <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete">
                  </FieldRef>
                  <Value Type="Number">1</Value>
                </Neq>
              </Or>
              <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
                </FieldRef>
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                  <Today>
                  </Today>
                </Value>
              </Geq>
            </And>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="4" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Completed_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" Url="completed.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <Geq>
              <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete">
              </FieldRef>
              <Value Type="Number">1.0</Value>
            </Geq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="5" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,My_Tasks;" MobileView="True" MobileDefaultView="False" Url="MyItems.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issues.png?rev=23" ReqAuth="TRUE">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="StrikeThroughPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <In>
              <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" LookupId="TRUE" />
              <Values>
                <Value Type="Integer">
                  <UserID />
                </Value>
              </Values>
            </In>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="7" Type="HTML" TabularView="FALSE">
        <JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <Toolbar Position="After" Type="Freeform">
          <IfHasRights>
            <RightsChoices>
              <RightsGroup PermAddListItems="required" />
            </RightsChoices>
            <Then>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<div class="tb"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/caladd.gif?rev=23" alt="" />&#160;<a class="ms-addnew" id="idAddNewTask" href="]]></HTML>
              <URL Cmd="New" />
              <HTML><![CDATA[" onclick="javascript:NewItem(']]></HTML>
              <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
                <URL Cmd="New" />
              </ScriptQuote>
              <HTML><![CDATA[', true);javascript:return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
              <HTML>Add new task</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[</a></div>]]></HTML>
            </Then>
          </IfHasRights>
        </Toolbar>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Checkmark">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Status">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="8" Type="GANTT" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,ganttChart;" Url="gantt.aspx" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Predecessors">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="GUID">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="GanttTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate" Type="GanttStartDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="GanttEndDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="PercentComplete" Type="GanttPercentComplete">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Predecessors" Type="GanttPredecessors">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ParentID" Type="HierarchyParentID">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate" Type="TimelineDueDate">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query />
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="9" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,userinfo_schema_calendarview;" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/events.png?rev=23" TabularView="FALSE" Url="calendar.aspx" MobileUrl="_layouts/15/mobile/viewdaily.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewHeader>
        </ViewHeader>
        <ViewBody>
        </ViewBody>
        <ViewFooter>
        </ViewFooter>
        <ViewEmpty>
        </ViewEmpty>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
        <ViewFields>

          <FieldRef Name="StartDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Title">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <ViewData>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarMonthTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarWeekTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarWeekLocation">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="CalendarDayTitle">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="Location" Type="CalendarDayLocation">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewData>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <DateRangesOverlap>
              <FieldRef Name="StartDate">
              </FieldRef>
              <FieldRef Name="DueDate">
              </FieldRef>
              <Value Type="DateTime">
                <Month>
                </Month>
              </Value>
            </DateRangesOverlap>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="10" Name="eb633ca3-52e7-4296-8b77-3997d05dcbe7" DisplayName="ExtraView" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" Url="ExtraView.aspx">
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
          <FieldRef Name="Title" />
          <FieldRef Name="Status" />
          <FieldRef Name="StartDate" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query />
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

[Edit]
Apparently its not possible to add new Views with a new BaseViewId to a list with only a custom schema. But why is this not possible? Is it only possible when creating a list definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use custom schema attribute, you can't declare one more view.

You can remove an existing one and create your own, using the BaseViewID of the one you removed.

Answer (score -1):

You must give your view a unique SetupPath:

like

```
SetupPath="pages\extraviewpage.aspx"
```

since this path corresponds to the URL of the View that sharepoint will use to render it.

EDIT: Sorry about that, you should specify either a unique URL or a unique Path, witch you have already done.

Comment: When I change the setuppath, the solution cannot be deployed because it cannot find the file specified. Which is true because there is no pages\extraviewpage.aspx

Comment: You are correct, if you want to use standard display page you should not change the value for SetupPath, sorry about that

Comment: No problem. Every hint is worth a try

Comment: Sorry did not know that this was -2 for your reputation. My mistake.

Comment: Hehe it's okay, I did give you an incorrect answer after all!